# POSTGRES Compare a json arrays against another array

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres jsonb column called `items` having

```
 [{"id":"","name":""},{"id":"","name":""}]
```

I need to compare this whole column with the data

```
 [{"id":"","name":""},{"id":"","name":""}]
```

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to the site. I'm not sure your question is clear at this point. Can you add more details about what you expect to happen. Those 2 code blocks are exactly the same so what are you trying to compare?

Comment: If you are sure both arrays hold the items in the same order, you can simply do a `items = '[{"id":"","name":""},{"id":"","name":""}]'::jsonb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean an exact string match then you can do:

`SELECT * FROM table where items::text = '[{"id":"","name":""},{"id":"","name":""}]'`

Note that JSONB does not necessarily keep the order in the objects the same so it might not work all the time because the order of items might change on the output.

You can lookup the Postgres docs for more advanced JSON operations where you can actually look inside the values.

Comment: `where items = '[{"id":"","name":""},{"id":"","name":""}]'::jsonb` would work as well, but only if the items in the array are in the same order.